# hdinsight new hiveconnection not working

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive, nullreferenceexception, azure-hdinsight

Im using the hdinsight hadoop locally and after successfully running mapreduce jobs on the hdfs i am trying with hive, unfortunately i am getting errors when running the hive query when creating a table.

I got the following code from another stack solution as i am only running it locally and not using azure:

```
var db = new HiveConnection(
                    webHCatUri: new Uri("http://localhost:50111"),
                    userName: (string)"hadoop", password: (string)null);

// also tried command with no ; inside quotes
string command = "CREATE TABLE log4jLogs(t1 string, t2 string, t3 string," +
                                  "t4 string, t5 string, t6 string, t7 string)" +
                  "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';";
db.ExecuteHiveQuery(command).Wait();
```

This always throws an exception after a while of processing. the exception is:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.NullReferenc eException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
>   Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive.HiveConnection.<ExecuteHiveQuery>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationTo ken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreateActorsTable() in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\ Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Pr ogram.cs:line
>   90
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not se t to an instance of an object.    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
>   Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive.HiveConnection.d__2.MoveNext()<---

I have checked the logs from hadoop in which i get the following:

> java.io.IOException: Invalid status dir URI   at
>   org.apache.hcatalog.templeton.tool.TempletonControllerJob$LaunchMapper.run(TempletonControllerJob.java:155)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:762)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260) Caused by:
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index
>   6: asv://{0}@{1}/6f8d3bc9-89a2-4e1d-9749-2805d31f05f0     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)   at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3148)     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3059)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3015)  at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:577)     at
>   org.apache.hcatalog.templeton.tool.TempletonUtils.addUserHomeDirectoryIfApplicable(TempletonUtils.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.hcatalog.templeton.tool.TempletonControllerJob$LaunchMapper.run(TempletonControllerJob.java:152)
>     ... 7 more

I would love if anyone could point me in the right direction with this as i cannot work out why this is failing.

Comment: did you find a solution? i am have the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hive connection first have to start the hive server. Hive server executables are residing in hdp/hive/bin. Using command prompt start the **hiveserver2.exe** . You can modify the Hive server configuration using hiveserver2.xml which is also residing in the same folder.